# HasValue giving value 0 instead of Nothing

Tags: vb.net

Question is simple, when I pass CustomClass which is `Nothing` into `Run` method at the end in `Query` method `second.HasValue` is showing `0`. Shouldn't be `Nothing`?

```
Public Function Run() As Boolean
       Return Query(if(CustomClass IsNot Nothing, CustomClass.Id, Nothing))
End Function

Public Function Query(second As Integer?) As Boolean
    ...
    If second.HasValue Then
        'value = 0 !
        Else
           'some query
        End If

    ...
End Function
```

Comment: Is `CustomClass.Id` of type `Integer?` or `Integer`?

Comment: we're missing some info. What's the type of `CustomClass.Id` - is it nullable or not? If it's not then that explains the result you're seeing. If it was actually a nullable int then the value would indeed be Nothing. But a normal int cannot be Nothing so it just uses the default value instead (which is 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a VB.NET oddity. [`Nothing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing) doesn't only mean [`null`(C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null) but also [`default`(C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default). So it will return the default value of a given type. You can even assign `Nothing` to an `Integer` variable(or any other reference- or value-type) for that reason.

In this case the compiler decided that `Nothing` means the default value of `Integer` which is 0. Why? Because he needs to find an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/implicit-and-explicit-conversions) to the `Id`-property which is `Int32`.

If you want a `Nullable(Of Int32)` use:

```
Return Query(if(CustomClass IsNot Nothing, CustomClass.Id, New Int32?()))
```

Because i mentioned C#, if you try the same there you will get a compiler error that there is no implicit conversion between `null` and `int`. In VB.NET there is one, the default value 0.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the inline `If`-statement.

It will return an `Integer` instead of an `Integer?` because `CustomClass.Id` apparently is of type `Integer`.

So you can either define `CustomClass.Id` as `Integer?` or use `CType` to convert it to `Integer?` in the inline `If`.

```
Public Function Run() As Boolean
    Return Query(if(CustomClass IsNot Nothing, CType(CustomClass.Id, Integer?), Nothing))
End Function
```

Comment: I think that should be `CType(CustomClass.Id, Integer?)`, otherwise it's effectively the same as the original.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Correct, that was a typo.